# How to implement a loading screen in JavaFX when opening another application

Tags: java, windows, javafx, loader

I am currently working on a programm where I try to open another application (such as eg Notepad) from a link. 
As sometimes it will take some time to open that programm, I wanted to implement either a loading screen, or simply indicate the program being loaded by changing the cursorstyle, but only for the period, until the application has been launched and is running.
Whenever I try to implement this feature the cursor is only changed after the application is already running.
The application is launched via the following method:

```
public void run(String path) {
    try {
        Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process process = runTime.exec(path);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            new Warnings().AppOpenError(dataBean.getLinkPath());
        }
        process.destroy();
        dataBean.getPrimaryStage().getScene().setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        new Warnings().ioException(e);
    }
}
```

How can I achieve the loading bar only being shown during loadingtime of the application?

Comment: maybe this help http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/progress.htm

Comment: You will need to get some information of the program that it has finished loading e.g. from the console output steam. Otherwise this will not be possible.